# Django CMS + Django Comments = 404

Tags: django, django-cms

I am a novice user of Django 1.4.2. I have played with it some weeks but I keep getting stuck at the same point: a 404 if I go to a pre-set url...

URLS.PY:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
    (r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns    # Example:
```

I have followed the Django CMS and some other plugins so many times, but I keep receiving a 404 error when i want to preview an url. In this case I have successfully installed Django Comments, I am able to create comments (in the backend), but if I want to preview them in the front-end...404. Is there something wrong with my URLS.PY?

```
example.com/en/comments -> 404
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which of your urls is supposed to match that comment example?

Comment: admin and root are working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple question: do you see `en` or something like `(?P<language>...)` anywhere in your URL conf? Then why would you expect that you would get anything but a 404 for `/en/comments/`?

Further, including the Django CMS urls at `^$` (root) essentially passes all processing of URLs to its urls.py, so anything you add to urls.py after that is for all intents and purposes ignored. If you want to include something else, it must go *before* that in urls.py, and it will then be available at the urlpattern you specified, in this case, just `/comments/`, not `/en/comments/`.

Comment: Indeed, it don't see `en` in my URL conf. Unfortunately [link](example.com/comments) doesn't work either.

Comment: Your second feedback is very helpful, I did't know that it works that way. Thank you for the insight! However, just as I pointed out below, even after properly reordering the urls I get the same page not found error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

?

'example.com/comments/' should work. If you get the same error make sure you have 'django.contrib.comments' added to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py file. You may also run 'manage.py syncdb' in order for the tables related to the 'comments' app to be created.

Where the 'en/' comes from anyway? Is it a hard-coded URL in your app page or is it inserted by you manually?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I reorded the urls but sadly without any postive effect. I also checked [link](example.com/comments) of course, but the same result. I added it to activated the comments framework in INSTALLED_APPS, even did a syndb & migrate and double checked the tables in mysql databse. No effects, but thanks for the pointers!

BTW, the `en` comes from: 
    `LANGUAGES = [
        ('en', 'English'),
    ]`

Which is default when you install Django CMS.